# MySQL Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory. I want to create two table in which users table is main table which has foreign key for courses

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
// User Entity
package example.registrationlogindemo.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
courses course;

@Column(nullable=false)
private String name;

@Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
private String email;

@Column(nullable=false)
private String password;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
        name="users_roles",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")})
private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public courses getCourse() {
    return course;
}

public void setCourse(courses course) {
    this.course = course;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public List<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

}

//courses entity
package example.registrationlogindemo.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "courses")
public class courses {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "user_id")
private Long user_id;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "courses")
User user;

@Column(nullable=false)
private Long java;

public Long getUser_id() {
    return user_id;
}

public void setUser_id(Long user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public Long getJava() {
    return java;
}

public void setJava(Long java) {
    this.java = java;
}
}
```

Error:
Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Unknown mappedBy in:
example.registrationlogindemo.entity.courses.user, referenced property unknown:
example.registrationlogindemo.entity.User.courses
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unknown mappedBy in: example.registrationlogindemo.entity.User.course, referenced property unknown: example.registrationlogindemo.entity.courses.users
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1753) ~[spring-beans-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:604) ~[spring-beans-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:526) ~[spring-beans-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1141) ~[spring-context-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:916) ~[spring-context-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:592) ~[spring-context-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:430) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0-M4.jar:3.0.0-M4]
at example.registrationlogindemo.RegistrationLoginDemoApplication.main(RegistrationLoginDemoApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown mappedBy in: example.registrationlogindemo.entity.User.course, referenced property unknown: example.registrationlogindemo.entity.courses.users
at org.hibernate.cfg.OneToOneSecondPass.doSecondPass(OneToOneSecondPass.java:170) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.1.Final.jar:6.1.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1781) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.1.Final.jar:6.1.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1738) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.1.Final.jar:6.1.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.1.Final.jar:6.1.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1350) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.1.Final.jar:6.1.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1421) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.1.Final.jar:6.1.1.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362) ~[spring-orm-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:338) ~[spring-orm-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1799) ~[spring-beans-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1749) ~[spring-beans-6.0.0-M5.jar:6.0.0-M5]
... 16 common frames omitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mismatch between property "course" an class User and the "mappedBy" value of "courses" in class courses:

Class User:

```java
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
courses course;
```

Class courses:

```java
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "courses")
User user;
```

The mappedBy value should have a value of "course".

PS: You should refactor the class "courses" to "Courses" to follow the Java conventions.

PS: Your domain model looks suspicious, as I'd would assume a ManyToMany relationship between a User and a Course.